# Firebase A/B testing from Backend

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-ab-testing, abtest

it is possible to configure firebase A/B testing from backend?
I want to be a proxy from our front-ends (app, web) customers.
But i cannot find any APIs or Documentation from backend.